# Absolute positioned element inside relative positioned element gets clipped

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is simple. A relative positioned div has an absolute positioned div as child. This absolute positioned child element gets clipped by the relative positioned element.

I should not make any changes to the relative positioned element, because it is a third party grid control. Changing it breaks the grid layout.

I tried setting `overflow:visible` on both the relative positioned div element and absolute positioned div element but nothing works.

Can anyone please suggest an idea to overcome this clipping problem?

```html
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;border:2px solid black;">
<div class="parent" style="position:relative;left:200px;width:300px;height:300px;border:2px solid black;overflow:hidden;">
  Relative Parent
  <div class="child" style="position:absolute;left:-100px;border:2px solid black;">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Absolute positioned div element
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: left: -100px will position the child div at -100px with respect to relatively positioned div.. With the CSS you've written, this is bound to happen

Comment: Your CSS has a typo in it. (The same typo, lots of times).

Comment: If I fix the typo, the content is clipped by the viewport, not by the container.

Comment: let me edit the code

Comment: @all I have edited my code

Comment: Not able find any cliping in your code. it might get overlapped which can be resolved using z-index.

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hari1_prasad/wvfez9b2/)

Comment: `style="position:absolute;left:-100px;border:2px solid black;"` this is what's causing the clipping `left:-100px;`, which is not a clip it's just moved to the left outside out the viewport

Comment: @ZohirSalak, i have updated code. now you can see the left side of absolute div getting clipped by relative div not by viewport

Comment: @all sorry about code editing as this is my first time

Comment: @AnkurMittal, I have modified the css. You can see that absolute positioned element gets clipped by relative positioned element not by viewport

Comment: if you would remove `left:-100px` from `div.child` and `width:300px;` from the container there will be no clipping

Comment: @ZohirSalak 'div.parent' is the grid control at the centre of the page. I need to place the 'div.child' partially outside the 'div.parent' element. But 'div.child' gets clipped if i place it left side of the 'div.parent' element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I've edited the snippet to show a way to wrap the text in the `td` element in case this is what you were trying to accomplish.

---

If you can't edit the HTML of the child div directly, you can change its attributes with JavaScript. The `style` attribute's `left` property having a value of `-100px` is what's causing your pain.

If you negate the default style attribute entirely, your CSS will be allowed to take over the styling, and the div will be at your mercy.

Try something like:

```js
const childDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];
childDiv.style = "";
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 100px;
}

.child td{
  width: 100px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;border:2px solid black;">
  <div class="parent" style="position:relative;left:200px;width:300px;height:300px;border:2px solid black;overflow:hidden;">
    Relative Parent
    <div class="child" style="position:absolute;left:-100px;border:2px solid black;">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Absolute positioned div element
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Alternatively, you could set the style imperatively in the JavaScript (like `childDiv.style="position: absolute; top: 100px;"`, but relying on CSS for this is a best practice unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my code to explain this issue better. The relative positioned element is grid. I need to place the absolute placed content partially in grid and partially outside the grid. There is enough space to the left of the grid, so it should be visible

Comment: I read your updated question (and copied your code to make the snippet in the answer.) Is this what you were trying to do, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: sorry I have updated many times so you may copied code before the final version. There is some misunderstanding

Comment: I guess the misunderstanding my be what do you mean by "clipped". I added styling for the `td` element, which may be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually this child div element is cloned from a row in grid for drag and drop user interaction. Users will drop it anywhere outside the grid. At present when I drag this cloned row outside the grid, it gets clipped. So asked this question with a simple example

Comment: Thanks again. Its the 'overflow:hidden' attribute in 'div.parent' that clips the 'div.child' content. I will check if I can do anything about it

Comment: Best I can tell from the code I have, the `overflow: hidden` doesn't cause a problem -- but the context of your issue (the cloned and dropped node) isn't visible to the rest of us so I could easily be missing the problem. If `overflow: hidden` is the culprit, maybe you can do something like `document.addEventListener("drop", showOverflow); function showOverflow(event){ event.target.style.overflow="visible"; }` (And see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drop_event if this kind of code isn't familiar to you.) Or just go with the classic "keep tryin stuff till it works" :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just thought of an alternate using fixed positioning of div element instead of absolute positioned element. This adds the additional overhead of manually locating the div based on mouse position. I thought there might be a css property available which i don't know of, that can make the absolute positioned element work like a fixed position element and avoid the manual overhead

Comment: The site says my vote will reflect after my score reaches 15+. Thanks for your help